# Componente de Angularjs con typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Estoy intentando pasar un código viejo de angularjs a typescript para darle un poco de limpieza al código, el sitio funciona con el código vanilla Js.

Este es el código viejo de javascript

```
Configuration = angular.module("Configuration");

function init(
    $scope, $rootScope, $localStorage,
    CompanyService
) {
    this.$onInit = () => {
        console.log("initializing");

        $rootScope.headerSettings = {
            header_title: "Configuración de eventos"
        };
        this.edit = null;
        this.invite = null;
        this.assist = null;


        this.companyId = ("foo" !== $localStorage.user.type) ?
            $localStorage.user.current_company_id : $localStorage.user.company_id;

        CompanyService.getEventsList(this, false, setEventsList);
    };

    let setEventsList = (data) => {
        this.eventsList = data;
    };

    $scope.$on("refreshEventsList", () => {
        this.edit = null;
        this.invite = null;
        this.assist = null;

        CompanyService.getEventsList(this, true, setEventsList);
    });

    this.addEvent = (newEvent) => {

    };

}

Configuration.component("eventManager", {
    templateUrl: "urlToTemplate.html",
    controllerAs: "ctrl",
    bindings: {},
    controller: [
        "$scope", "$rootScope", "$localStorage",
        "CompanyService",
        "ENV_CONFIG", "configuration",
        "ApiCallsFactory", "NotificationsFactory",
        init
    ]
});
```

Y esto es lo que yo estoy escribiendo en typescript

```
// Importaciones
import angular, { IComponentOptions } from 'angular';
import GeneralConfiguration from './utils/configuration';

// Interfaces
interface ComponentConfig {
    templateUrl: string;
    controllerAs: string;
    bindings: any;
    controller: any[];
}

class Event {
    config:   ComponentConfig;
    scope:    any;
    general:  any;
    params:   any;
    root:     any;
    local:    any;
    env:      any;
    conf:     any;
    company$: any;
    calls$:   any;
    notif$:   any;
    
    constructor() {
        this.config.templateUrl  = '/app/modules/ConfigurationModule/components/events/events.html';
        this.config.controllerAs = 'ctrl';
        this.config.bindings     = {};
        this.config.controller   = [
            "$scope", "$rootScope", "$localStorage",
            "CompanyService",
            "ENV_CONFIG", "configuration",
            "ApiCallsFactory", "NotificationsFactory"
        ];

    }

    init(
        scope: any, root: any, local: any,
        env: any, conf: any,
        company$: any, calls$: any, notif$: any
    ): void {
        this.scope    = scope;
        this.root     = root;
        this.local    = local;
        this.conf     = conf;
        this.env      = env;
        this.company$ = company$;
        this.calls$   = calls$;
        this.notif$   = notif$;


    }

    $onInit(): void {
        this.scope.headerSettings.header_title = 'Configuración de eventos';
        const general   = new GeneralConfiguration( this.local.user );
        const companyId = general.getCompany();
        this.params = {
            companyId,
            newEvent:   {},
            eventsList: [],
            edit:       undefined,
            invite:     undefined,
            assist:     undefined,
            startOpen:  undefined,
            endOpen:    undefined
        };

        this.getEvents();

        this.scope.$on( 'refreshEventsList', () => {
            this.params.edit   = undefined;   
            this.params.invite = undefined;   
            this.params.assist = undefined;
            this.getEvents();
        });

    }


    getEvents(): void {
        this.company$.getEventsList( 
            this.params, 
            false, 
            ( data: any[] ) => this.params.eventsList = data 
        );
    }

    addEvent( newEvent: any ): void {

    } 
}

// Declaración general
const ANGULAR = angular.module('Configuration');

// Seteo de componente
const CONFIG = new Event;
ANGULAR.component( 'eventManager', CONFIG );
```

Me sale un error cuando le paso `CONFIG` al componente

> Type 'Event' has no properties in common with type
> 'IComponentOptions'.ts(2559)

Intenté extender la clase de IComponentOptions pero no me deja

Será que quizá este perdiendo el tiempo? Que me sugieren para hacer una migración modular. Aclaro, **el cliente no quiere (aún) pasar a Angular 2+**

**Me gustaría me compartieran si existe alguna librería, tutorial o algo que pueda agilizar esta migración**

Comment: Por un lado tenes un error de que `ComponentConfig` es una interfaz, no podes usarla para instanciar objetos. Deberías crear una interfaz `interface IComponentConfig` (_que podría extender de `IComponentOptions`_) y luego la clase que utilice la interfaz `class ComponentConfig implements IComponentConfig`. Aparte de eso, tu pregunta se basa en opiniones y ya tenes cierta antiguedad como para que te diga que no deberías crear este tipo de preguntas